# Passing data to other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Form.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Form extends React.Component{

    handlePatientDisease(e){
        this.setState({
            patientdisease: e.target.value
        })
    }
        handlePatientPresentIllness(e){
        this.setState({
            patientpresentillness: e.target.value
        })
    }
    handlePatientName(e){
    let patientName = e.target.value
    this.setState({ patientName })
    this.props.onPatientNameChange.value
}

handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Patient name changed to:", patientName.value)
    }

render () {
    return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> 
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label> Nome do Paciente </label>
                <input type="text" name="patientName" id="patientName" placeholder="nome do paciente"  onChange={this.handlePatientName.bind(this)} />

            </li>
            <li>
                <label> Doença 
                <input type="text" name="patientdisease" placeholder="disease"/>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label> Histórico 
                <input type="text" name="patientpresentillness" placeholder="historia do paciente"/>
                </label>
            </li>


            <li>
                <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
            </li>
        </ul>

</form>
        );
}


}
```

So, Now I already can get the data submitted in that form and show it on console. How do I display in another component now? I want to that data as a list item in that component below:

Sidebar.js

```
import React from 'react'
import patientName from './Form'

export default class Sidebar extends React.Component{
    handlePatientNameChange(patientName){
        console.log("Patient name changed to:", patientName)
    }

render () {
    return(
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
              <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">

                <li><a href="#">Alexandre Miranda</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Felipe Neves</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Andressa Lyra</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Artur Lyra</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Antonio Lyra</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ricardo Lyra</a></li>
                // When I submit, I want to show the patientName here as a list item....            



              </ul>

            </div>
           </div>
          </div>

        );
}

}
```

Comment: There's not enough code shown...essentially what you need to do is have the form data as an object in the parent component. Pass it to the form component and onSubmit, pass it back to the parent component and set the state of it from there. Also have that form data passed to the sidebar component and so then when state updates, it will update that component as well

Comment: @erichardson30 Could you see my project and help me out please? https://github.com/alex42miranda/Test

Comment: @erichardson30 I already opened an issue about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some sort of common data store that is accessible by both components, your form and your sidebar.

The naive approach would be to create a global array that contains your list of patients. This is accessible from anywhere in your application and can be written from the form, as well as read from the sidebar. However, there are plenty of discussions why global variables may be a bad idea, so this solution is most likely not the preferred one.

---

A better option would be to **keep the list in the `state` of a common ancestor** component of the form and the sidebar. Say, if your app is structured like this:

```
<App>
    <Form />
    <Sidebar />
</App>
```

, instead of keeping it in the state of `Form`, transfer it to `App`, store it in its state and pass it down to `Sidebar` via its props.

---

Once your application becomes more complex, you should **think about a more general approach to storing your application's data** in a central place outside of your React components. While there are dozens of valid approaches to this problem, you could look into [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) or [Redux](http://redux.js.org/index.html) as a starting point.

Comment: Ok @TimoSta. Could you see my project and help me out please? github.com/alex42miranda/Test – Alexandre Miranda

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't show what's the connection between the Sidebar and the Form component. Are they rendered within the same parent component?

Generally speaking, you need to add callback to the `Sidebar` component into the `Form` component. Callback will be called on submit with the new value. Sidebar component will then update its state and re-render.